# How to load a CSV file into Hive table?

Tags: python, linux, hive, pyhive

I'm trying to load a CSV from 1 remote server to a Hive client on a different server using Python:

I'm opening the CSV file on remote server:

```
with open("/path/to/csv/file/" +self.file_to_load, "rb") as file:
    csv_file = file.read()
```

Now i'm looking for the command to load that csv_file into Hive (which is on a different server) using pyhive connect;

```
conn_h = hive.connect(host=self.hive_host, port=10000, auth='NONE',username=self.user)
    
query = "LOAD LOCAL DATA INPATH 'file://" + self.path_to_file + "' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE " + self.tgt_hive_table
conn_h.cursor.execute(query)
```

I'm looking for a way to load csv file without saving the actual file on server

Comment: i think you actually will need to upload the file to the HDFS for this to work, any reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: That's what i ended up doing @martineau, I created an external table on the csv file.
The reason was security issues.

Comment: I think you should have addressed your comment to @Cyclonecode, not me.